How do I extract the domain values associated with a ColorDataFunction?
I want to extract the Domain values of 380 and 750 from the following ColorDataFunction:

I'm missing something on the language-level—they don't seem to be Attributes, neither do they seem to be Properties (or I'm just using PropertyValue wrong)—what is it that I'm looking at in the grey box and how do I extract values from it?

Look at the parts; which then leads to ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"][[3]]

@BobHanlon - Hm, how can parts be associated with "keys" like "Name" and "Gradient" though? (Not denying that it works—just wondering if that it works but there's more to the state behind the scenes.) I can agree with the 2 close votes so far that I am missing some fundamental knowledge; I'd disagree it's easily found in documentation. What is the name of this pattern that shows up as such in a grey box of key-value pairs?

Look at the output of ColorData["VisibleSpectrum"] // InputForm, which is ColorDataFunction["VisibleSpectrum", "Physical", {380, 750}, Blend["VisibleSpectrum", #1] & ].

Regarding the "easily found in documentation": It's the 7th bullet point in ColorData.

@Domen - Ah I did miss that. But what I was looking for in documentation that I couldn't find was more general—what this grey box was and how key-value pairs could be associated with a function. I found documentation about Attributes and Properties but they did not seem relevant and I didn't know what else to call these things. Maybe I have a more fundamental misunderstanding.

Some things you can do
Get range
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", "Range"]


{380, 750}

Extract all elements
Table[ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", i], {i, 380, 750}]


Extract single element (magnified)
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", 550]


Get its RGB value
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", 550] // InputForm


RGBColor[0.,1.,0.]

Get image
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", "Image"]


ColorRules
Gradient color schemes don't accept ColorRules or ColorList
properties
ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", "ColorRules"]


Missing["NotApplicable"]

But we can mimic ColorRules as follows:
With[{cr = ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", "Range"]},
  Thread[Range @@ cr -> 
    Table[ColorData["VisibleSpectrum", i], 
      Evaluate[{i, Splice @ cr}]]]][[;; ;; 5]]


For other color schemes (which run from 0 to 1):
With[{cr = Range[100]},
 Thread[cr -> Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i], Evaluate[{i, cr/100}]]]]


